hi i am learing Next.js nowdays and i want to build a fullstack app but i get error if i click to singIn button
route.ts
import { authOptions } from "@/utils/auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";


const handler = NextAuth(authOptions) ;
export { handler as GET, handler as POST  }




auth.ts

import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
});

export default NextAuth(authOptions)

.env

NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_SECRET="mypassword"
#oUDyxEFbhHqi9Iy8/HUSmsjDvXP3e03EDk0zVi5Lt/c=

GITHUB_ID=Ov23lice5YBjPbwuXuF8
GITHUBT_SECRET=4a86b3bbe0c5a89b90bb35ea32ac71771dc39ae7

page.tsx
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const LoginPage = () => {

  const {data,status}=useSession();
  console.log(data,status)
  const router=useRouter();
  if(status==="loading"){
    return <p>Loading..</p>
  }
  if(status==="authenticated"){
    router.push("/")
  }


 <button onClick={()=>signIn("github")} className="flex gap-4 p-4 ring-1 ring-orange-100 rounded-md">
          <FaGithub className="text-4xl bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-600 via-green-500 to-indigo-400 text-white rounded-full p-1 " />
            <span>Sign in with Github</span>
          </button>

hi i am learing Next.js nowdays and i want to build a fullstack app but i get error if i click to singIn button
error :
POST /api/auth/_log 500 in 357ms
⨯ [TypeError: options.providers is not iterable]
⨯ [TypeError: options.providers is not iterable]
GET /api/auth/error 500 in 432ms
undefined loading
GET /login 200 in 928ms
⨯ [TypeError: options.providers is not iterable]
⨯ [TypeError: options.providers is not iterable]
GET /api/auth/session 500 in 145ms
Console Error :
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] "\nhttps://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error" "Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': Unexpected end of JSON input" {}
api/auth/_log:1
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

since a week i am trying to rectify it but i cannot solve the problem i hope someone could help me
